# Scala - DirectoryWatcher library; Thread is not blocked

Tags: java, scala, directory, file-watcher

I am new to scala and have been trying to implement the directory watcher using **https://index.scala-lang.org/gmethvin/directory-watcher/directory-watcher-better-files/0.13.0** library, but I am facing watching a directory **recursively**. I am running in Windows system.

**Code**

```
import better.files._
import io.methvin.better.files._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val myDir = File("/directory/to/watch/")
val watcher = new RecursiveFileMonitor(myDir) {
  override def onCreate(file: File, count: Int) = println(s"$file got created")
  override def onModify(file: File, count: Int) = println(s"$file got modified $count times")
  override def onDelete(file: File, count: Int) = println(s"$file got deleted")
}

//process is not blocked here - END is printing
watcher.start()

println("END")
```

**Problem**

The process is not getting blocked at **watcher.start()** not sure what I am missing, as per the library spec, it is specified that for Windows use **ExtendedWatchEventModifier.FILE_TREE**.

How to use this ExtendedWatchEventModifier.FILE_TREE parameter??

am I missing something in the above code??

**Findings**

1. I tried to run the **start()** method in separate thread but no luck.
2. I debugged and found that **start()** method is internally calling **DirectoryWatcher.watch()** but in a different **ExecutionContext**, I am not able to debug that **watch()** method, basically the debug point is not going to **DirectoryWatcher**. Not sure how it works.

Please let me know what am I am missing? Please let me know if more details are required.

Comment: Everything is acting as expected, as you can see, watch.start requires an implicit execution context, which means kind of like an ExecutorService in java, which defines how tasks should be processed in multiple threads, so if they are run in separate threads, they do not block the main thread, that's the basic concept of threads.

Comment: ok, but if I want to block that thread / wait on a future object for that implicit execution context which **watch.start** uses, how should I go about, basically I want to watch a directory continuously.

Comment: It's not recommended at all, but I understand that sometimes you might need to block concurrent process, so maybe watcher.start().onComplete(_ => global.shutDownNow()) would help, you can also use Await. (Again, It's not recommended at all)

Comment: unfortunately, no it did not work there is no method like onComplete in watcher.start()....

Comment: Oh so it doesn't return a `Future` instance, since onComplete is a method of future, anyway, you can block your main thread using various solutions, my suggestion is to expect some signal from your console (using a scanner which scans an input stream like your console), so before `println("END")`, do this: `new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine()`. this will wait for a string from terminal, so you can exit your application writing anything into your console.